# Cannot find or open the PBD file

Tags: c#, breakpoints, visual-studio-2022, debug-symbols

Working on an ASP.NET C# web application project in Visual Studio 2022. I've been having the infamous "Breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document" error when trying to debug.

I've poured over questions here looking for solutions. I am definitely running the debug configuration, and just found out that, in the Module window, absolutely nothing had loaded.

I found a solution for getting some to load by switching the browser I was debugging in (Google Chrome -> Edge). But, now that I have modules in the window, most have "Cannot find or open the PDB file" under the "Symbol Status" column, and my breakpoints are still encountering the same error.

I have been at this for a day or two now with no solutions. I'm not sure where to go from here. Any advice, solutions?

Diagnosed that no symbols had loaded for my project, and expected breakpoints to start working once they had. Symbols have still not loaded properly and breakpoints are still broken.

Comment: What type of web application are you working on? Blazor, Asp.Net Core, Angular?

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson ASP.NET. I'll edit to add that in

Comment: First thing to try is clean all the VS metadata. Close the project, delete the bin and obj folders in all projects, delete the .vs folder, delete the .suo and .user files. If that doesn't work, copy the csproj into a new solution and see if it reproduces the issue

Answer (score -1):

When my breakpoints failed (C#/.NET/VS 2022 Community), my research on this issue (primarily here on SO) focused on issues with missing PDB files.  Indeed, reviewing Debug::Windows::Modules indicated problems with numerous PDB files.

My research included reading through most if not all related posts here at SO, including the numerous related questions that were listed below this question before I posted this potential answer.

I finally focused on one specific file, the PDB file for the specific software I was using, and contacted the sofware vendor's support team.  After digging in deeper with them, and trying many of the same proposed solutions offered, the tech suggested **uninstalling and re-installing Visual Studio**.

Maybe I missed this in the extensive offered answers here at SO, but I do not recall seeing this as a proposed answer.

Worked like a charm and my breakpoints are working again.

I still see various PDB issues listed in the Debug::Windows::Modules, but since my breakpoints are working I am, for now, ignoring the PDB issues.